# Instantiate an object and pass its name to constructor using c++ macro

Tags: c++, macros

Let's say

```cpp
class A {
   A(string name) {
       //....
   }
}
```

So when the object is created:

```cpp
A* objectNumber324 = new A("objectNumber324");
A* objectNumber325 = new A("objectNumber325");
```

In my case as the object names are pretty long, I am looking for macro to simplify that code to:

```cpp
CreateA(objectNumber325);
```

There is some discussion how to pass variable name to a function [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2328732/pass-variable-name-in-c). But that is not quite the same thing, as I want to create the object and pass its name to constructor.

Comment: This is almost never something you actually want to do, and this looks a lot like an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). You can, however, use exactly the same technique as you linked to; just write a macro that expands to a declaration.

Comment: What is the use-case for using the same "name" as the variable? What problem is that supposed to solve? And why can't you just do e.g. `std::vector<A> objects;` and then `objects.emplace_back("objectNumber324");` (possibly in a loop if you want sequential numbering)?

Comment: What definitions for `CreateA` have you tried?

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude this is actually creating some low level chip modeling, that these objects have very similar names like ports connections, and there are plenty of them. These name should be printed in logs. The main reason to keep code and log readable together.

Comment: Then you should definitely use a vector of object (or some other standard container, perhaps `std::unordered_map` to map from the "id" to the object) instead of distinct and separate variables.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```cpp
#include <string>
#include <iostream>

#define CreateA(name) \
        A* name = new A(#name)

// With type
#define CREATE_WITH_TYPE(type, name) \
        type* name = new type(#name)

// With name decoration
#define CREATE_WITH_DECO(type, name) \
        type* my_##name = new type(#name)

class A {
public:
   A(std::string name){
       std::cout << name << " created.\n";
   }
};

int main() {
    // example
    CreateA(objectNumber325);
    CREATE_WITH_TYPE(A, objectNumber324);
    CREATE_WITH_DECO(std::string, a_string);
    delete objectNumber324;
    delete objectNumber325;
    delete my_a_string;
}
```